# Counting a list starting from 0

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is my code so far, it is a text based file browser.  The users selects what drive or dir to browse by selecting the assigned number.  When you run the script it displays the output from 0 to whichever number of items there are.  But when displaying the contents of a folder it lists starting from 1 which throws off your selection.

```
from os import listdir
import win32api
```

---

```
#need help with this block
def glist(path):
    global nlist
    nlist = []
    for i in listdir(path):
        nlist.append(i)
        countf=len(nlist)
        print str(countf) + " " + str(i)
```

---

```
def getfiles(dir, filename):
    for i in listdir(dir):
        newtext=open(filename,'a')
        newtext.write("\n"+ "\n" + i)
        newtext.close()

def getdrives():
    global drives
    drives = win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings()
    drives = drives.split('\000')[:-1]
    for index, item in enumerate(drives):

      print index, item


print "Select which drive to work with: "
getdrives()

x = raw_input("Which Drive:")
glist(drives[int(x)])

y = raw_input("Select Folder: ")
glist(drives[int(x)] + nlist[int(y)])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better written as:

```
def glist(path):
    global nlist
    for idx, name in enumerate(listdir(path)):
        print '{} {}'.format(idx, name) 
    nlist.append(name)
```

But would reconsider using a `global` and returning a list from it instead...

Comment: @kojiro Nope - it was me that missed that - good spot - corrected post

Answer (score 0):

The *length* of a list is one more than the largest index in that list.

```
def glist(path):
    global nlist
    nlist = []
    for i in listdir(path):
        nlist.append(i)
        # Just subtract 1
        countf=len(nlist) - 1
        print str(countf) + " " + str(i)
```

That said, it's probably expensive to recalculate the length of a list at every iteration, particularly when you *know* it's growing by 1 at each step. You get the countf for free with [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) (which is, of course, zero-indexed).

```
def glist(path):
    global nlist
    nlist = []
    for countf, i in enumerate(listdir(path)):
        nlist.append(i)
        print str(countf) + " " + str(i)
```

Comment: thanks alot! that second block of code really helped and also worked!!